# Activator.createinstance(generic type, args) method is throwing exception

Tags: c#, generics, model-view-controller, activator

I have created a generic class with which to instantiate another unknown class.

We are passing the name of a class at run time though the below code, and already we have a class with parameter constructor, so same I am passing argument to create instance of class through activator.

When I run the code below however, it throws the following error:

> 'Constructor on type
>   eDebitCreditNote.Models.GenericClass`1[[eDebitCreditNote.Models.DC_Header_Vendor,
>   eDebitCreditNote, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]' not found.'

```
object[] args = new object[1] { values };
string classname = tblform.HeaderTable;
var sometype = Type.GetType("eDebitCreditNote.Models."+classname);
var genericType = typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { sometype });
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType,args);
```

Generic class code:

```
 namespace eDebitCreditNote.Models
    {
     public class GenericClass<T>
    {


        public T ObjectCreate<T>(object[] args)
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args); 

    }


        public IDictionary<string, object> FieldValues { get; set; }

    }
    }
```

Comment: So... can you post the constructor(s) of that generic class?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Pleas update your question using the link ***edit*** below your question, and add the code for `GenericClass`.

Comment: You are passing args = new object[1] { values }, but you don't have a constructor that takes 1 argument.